# TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined in node js code

Tags: javascript, node.js

i got error in if condition columnName=='name'

```
receivedValues = req.body
var usercolumns = ["name","price","duration","gender"];

    //FOR VALIDATING VALUES BEFORE SUBMISSION
    for(var iter=0;iter<usercolumns.length;iter++)

    {
        columnName = usercolumns[iter];
        console.log("column name",columnName);
        if(receivedValues[columnName] == undefined && (columnName=='name' || columnName=='price' || columnName=='duration' || columnName=='gender'))
        {
```

[image]

Comment: Are you sure 'receivedValues' are not undefined? - where does it come from?

Comment: Could you add the error text?

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
    at exports.create (D:\New\vabo\nodejs\controller\service.js:42:40)

Comment: receivedValues = req.body

Comment: now you can see my question

Answer (score 2):

Your `receivedValues` variable seems undefined here, you should add more code to question.

Comment: receivedValues = req.body

Comment: do you use [body-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser)? you should use it to get properties from req.body

Answer (score 0):

```
if(receivedValues && receivedValues[columnName] == undefined && (columnName=='name' || columnName=='price' || columnName=='duration' || columnName=='gender'))
```

you need to check if **receivedValues** exist

and you can optimize your code:

```
if(receivedValues && !columnName in receivedValues && columnName in usercolumns)
```